# Getting MIME type from Web Service Response header

Tags: c#, web-services, header, content-type

I invoke a web service provided by an external partner company. The web service returns files (.pdf, .dox, .png, ...) as a byte array.

If I would need to get the Header information (in detail I am interested in the content-type data) from the code, how can I get this information?

On our side, we are using VS 2010 and C# as language.

Here the code:

```
var client = new PublicService();
wsRequest request = new wsRequest();

var docInfo = new documentInfo();
docInfo.documentId = HSdocumentID;
docInfo.position = 1;

request.documentInfos =  { docInfo };
byte[] doc = client.deliver(deliverRequest);  //returns the file as byte array
```

Comment: What is the type of the web service that you are calling? is it a SOAP based web service, or is it a RESTful web service?

Comment: It is a SOAP web service. The developers of teh partner company said me that in the response header of the web service there is the data about content type. My question is how can I extract such information from my code?

Comment: If you have access to the WSDL of the Web Service please post the SOAP request/response sample of the required web method

Answer (score 0):

The RESPONSE header would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body><ns2:deliverResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.dalle.com/webservices/record/2012a">
  <return>
         <Include xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"  
                        href="cid:d3a@example.jaxws.sun.com"/>
  </return></ns2:deliverResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope> 

 Content-Id: <d3a@example.jaxws.sun.com> 
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
 Content-Type: application/pdf    <-- THIS IS THE INFO I NEED TO GET
```

> Check out if there are SOAP headers on the Web Method call that answer your question

On the web method I do not have any properties/attributes that refer to the header. Is there a general way to get the Response header or is the web service that should provide features to get it?

(I provided an answer, rather than a comment, due to the code to be copied)